# Island of "Name" vs island "Name". Proper usage of the preposition.

Tags: prepositions

For example why people use "Island of Jamaica" and "Macquarie Island". The latter doesn't use any preposition. When the preposition should be used and when not?

Comment: related, possbile duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131805/isle-vs-island

Comment: Don't we already have questions about "University of *X* vs *X* University" and "City of *Y* vs *Y* City"?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to EL&U. You might be interested in our sister site, English Language Learners; you can find it [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). It is very helpful in answering basic questions.

Comment: The suggested duplicate doesn't address the use of ***of***. I proposed what might be a general rule in [another question/answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130549/do-i-need-the-before-the-name-of-my-university-in-the-header).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use *The Isle of X* when that is its name in English: *The Isle of Man*, *The Isle of Dogs*, *The Isle of Capri*.

We use *X Island* when that is its name in English: *Canvey Island*, *Vancouver Island*, *Holy Island*.

We use just the simple name when that is its name in English: *Guernsey*, *Anglesey*, *Crete*; but for clarity we can use the descriptive phrase "The island of" in these cases.

There are some islands where there are alternative names: *Manhattan* or *Manhattan Island*; but in many cases, the name used is fixed as one of the three forms above.

I'm afraid you just have to learn which islands have which form of name.